# Objective-C - Convert this format P18Y9M4DT11H9M8S do NSDATE

Tags: ios, nsdate

I need to convert this date format `@"P18Y9M4DT11H9M8S"` (18 years, 9 month, 4 days, 11 hours, 9 minutesand 8s) to NSDate I can do this using an algorithm but I think there is an easy way to do it.

Comment: Any information about where you got that format from?

Comment: As a result of a web service.

Comment: That's an ["ISO 8601 Duration"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) and describes the length of a time interval and not an absolute point in time. So converting that to NSTimeInterval or perhaps NSDateComponents would make more sense ...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
NSString *myDate = @"P18Y9M4DT11H9M8S";

myDate = [myDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"P" withString:@""];
myDate = [myDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Y" withString:@"-"];
myDate = [myDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"M" withString:@"-"];
myDate = [myDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"D" withString:@"-"];
myDate = [myDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
myDate = [myDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"H" withString:@"-"];
myDate = [myDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"S" withString:@""];

NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH/mm/ss"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:myDate];

NSLog(@"date = %@", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateformattet and set the format and maybe some ither options. Then call -dateFromString. See the link for more detailed info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7